# sqlite3 cursor object returning unexpected result

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use the sqlite3 module in python to do a database lookup in a table that only has one column. The column contains phone numbers in the format of:

9545551212
???5551212

Here's what I am running in python:

```
import sqlite3
cti = '/home/user/test/cti.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(cti)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from ani_table_1 where number = 9545551212')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f6b435316c0>
```

When I run that exact same select statement in sqlite3 I get the expected result:

```
sqlite> select * from ani_table_1 where number = 9545551212;
9545551212
```

I'm using python 3.6.5 and sqlite 3.7.17

What have I got wrong in my code? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't iterate over the result. The `sqlite3` command line tool is not the same thing as Python code; the latter always prints the results, because it is a command-line tool and will make sure you don't get flooded with large result sets.

When accessing a database in code, however, the library can't assume you want to print out all the rows to the end user. You maybe wanted to do something different with the data instead.

So you need to loop over the cursor and print each row:

```
c.execute('select * from ani_table_1 where number = 9545551212')
for row in c:
    print(*row, sep='\t')
```

You may want to familiarise yourself with how the Python database API standard works; search around for a good tutorial. At a glance, [this specific tutorial](http://stackabuse.com/a-sqlite-tutorial-with-python/) looks like it covers the most important basics.

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation.